# Azure Service Bus: How to correctly check if Subscription already exists?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am trying the following code to check if the Azure Service Bus topic subscription already exists:

```
void Initialize()
{
    CreateTopicSubscription().Wait();
    //CreateTopicSubscription().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

async Task CreateTopicSubscription()
{
    managementClient = new ManagementClient(serviceBusConnectionString);
    if (!await managementClient.QueueExistsAsync(queueName).ConfigureAwait(false))
    { /* do some logic */ }
    if (!await managementClient.SubscriptionExistsAsync(queueName, "subscriptionName1"))
    {
        await managementClient.CreateSubscriptionAsync(new SubscriptionDescription(queueName, "subscriptionName1"));
    }
}
```

And I get the following error on the line with `SubscriptionExistsAsync`:

> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: 'The specified HTTP
>   verb (GET) is not valid. To know more visit
>   https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions. .
>   TrackingId:aa8b87cc-ea45-4fdc-be39-bf1877774b0e_G24,
>   SystemTracker:needspacetests:Queue:sc-messenger,
>   Timestamp:2019-12-18T11:33:45'

What am I doing wrong/missing here?

NOTES:

- I use a newly created Azure Service Bus in **Basic Plan** and newly (manually) created Queue.
- `queueName` has the value of an existing Queue.

Answer (score 4):

> I use a newly created Azure Service Bus in Basic Plan

The basic tier doesn't have topics and subscriptions. You should switch to the Standard tier if you need to use topics and subscriptions.